# NSLog macro to print out if it is on the main thread

Tags: objective-c, macros, nsthread, nslog

My current `DEB_LOG` macro extends `NSLog` to also print out the object, method, and line where it is being logged:

```
#define DEB_LOG(__FORMAT__,...) NSLog((@"%s line %d $ " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

---

I would also like to expand it to **report if it is on the main thread**, if possible.

```
[NSThread isMainThread]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#define DEB_LOG(__FORMAT__,...) NSLog((@"%s line %d%s $ " __FORMAT__), \
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, \
    ([NSThread isMainThread] ? " (main thread)" : ""), \
    ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

The output generated from

```
DEB_LOG(@"%@", @"Hello world");
```

is

```
-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] line 20 (main thread) $ Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can!

Could look something like this:

```
#define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) NSLog((@"%s line %d [Thread:%s] " __FORMAT__), \    
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ([NSThread isMainThread] ? "Main" : "Background"), \
 ##__VA_ARGS__)
```